# dynamic suggestion list using <ul><li> working fine on desktop for all browsers, but not working on iphones mobile devices

Tags: php, jquery, css, iphone, bootstrap-4

I have implemented dynamic suggestion list using ul & li tags, everything is working fine except iphone mobile devices.

Suggestion list display properly but **option selection is not working on iphone mobiles**.

**Suggestion list browser-insepct code:**

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                                          <div class="row">

                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="Cities-Counties">Cities/Counties:</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control city-input" name="city_1" id="city_1" placeholder="Enter City/County" autocomplete="off" value="">
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="cities[]" id="hid_city_1">
                                                    <ul class="serch-city" id="ulcity_1" style="display: none;"></ul>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control city-input" name="city_2" id="city_2" placeholder="Enter City/County" autocomplete="off" value="">
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="cities[]" id="hid_city_2">
                                                    <ul class="serch-city" id="ulcity_2" style="display: none;"></ul>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control city-input" name="city_3" id="city_3" placeholder="Enter City/County" autocomplete="off" value="">
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="cities[]" id="hid_city_3">
                                                    <ul class="serch-city" id="ulcity_3" style="display: none;"></ul>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control city-input" name="city_4" id="city_4" placeholder="Enter City/County" autocomplete="off" value="">
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="cities[]" id="hid_city_4">
                                                    <ul class="serch-city" id="ulcity_4" style="display: none;"></ul>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
```

**css code of class "search-city":**

```
.serch-city {
    width: 94%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1111;
    -webkit-z-index: 1111;
    max-height: 200px;
    background-color: #eff0f2;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**Relevant jQuery script code:**

```
$(document).delegate('.city-input', 'keyup', function()
    {
         var id = $(this).attr("id");

         var tmp = id.split("_");
         var city_cnt = tmp[1];        

         var serach_txt = $('#'+id+'').val();

         if(serach_txt!=''){ 
             s = {serach_txt:serach_txt};

             jQuery.ajax({

                    type: "post", 
                    url: '<?=BASE_URL?>clients/sort_cities',
                    data: s,
                    dataType:"json",

                    success: function(myObj) { 
                           var txt = "";
                           var count = Object.keys(myObj).length;  

                           if(myObj != null)
                           {
                              for(var i = 0;i < count; i++)
                              { 
                                  txt += '<li id="'+city_cnt+'_'+myObj[i].city_id+'" title="'+myObj[i].city_name+'" class="ctli">'+myObj[i].city_name+'</li>';
                              }
                           }

                           $("#ulcity_"+city_cnt+"").html(txt);
                           $("#ulcity_"+city_cnt+"").show();
                    }
             })
         }else{
             $("#ulcity_"+city_cnt+"").html('');
             $('#ulcity_'+city_cnt+'').hide();
         }   
    });

$(document).delegate('.ctli', 'click', function()
    { 
         var id = $(this).attr('id'); 
         var city_name = $(this).attr('title'); 

         var tmp = id.split("_");
         var city_id = tmp[1]; 
         var city_cnt = tmp[0];

         $('#city_'+city_cnt+"").val(city_name);
         $('#hid_city_'+city_cnt+"").val(city_id);
         $('#ulcity_'+city_cnt+"").hide();
    });
```

Everything is working properly, only for iphone mobiles suggestion list **item selection is not working**. please suggest me the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add:

.ctli { cursor:pointer }

iPhone recognise the click event by "cursor: pointer" css